# $_SESSION superglobals with Postman

Tags: php, xampp, postman

I have a host.php file that starts with the following:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION['role']) || $_SESSION['role'] != 'host') {
   header('location: index.php');
   }
?>
```

So for this reason, if *$_SESSION['role']* isn't set, then I will be returned to index.

Is it possible to include or pass the $_SESSION variables to the backend using **Postman**? Is there any function in Postman to do this or alternative ways to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to include or pass the $_SESSION variables to the backend using Postman?

Absolutely not, that would be a *huge* security hole.

> ​Is there any function in Postman to do this or alternative ways to achieve the same result?

You could write code to allow a `GET` parameter to be stuffed into (and thus override) the values in `SESSION`, but again, that is a really bad idea because it would allow any user to assume any role just by adjusting their URL.

If you're trying to test/dev against this page, you'd generally want to create a test user that belongs to that role, and then authenticate as that user.